# Redux-persist not persisting with expo on reload

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, asyncstorage, redux-persist

I am using following tech stack

1. react-native
2. expo
3. redux
4. redux-persist.

I have tried articles, docs as well as questions here also but not help. Its simply not persisting. I am using emulator and running through expo only. As soon i close the app and reload expo client it simply doesn't persist and ask me to login again.
I also tried using **AsyncStorage** but still not working.

Hers's my code:

**index.js**

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import ExpoFileSystemStorage from "redux-persist-expo-filesystem"
// import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: ExpoFileSystemStorage,
  whitelist: ["authReducer"],
};

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger))
);

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

**app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import { useFonts } from "@use-expo/font";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { ThemeProvider } from "react-native-elements";

import { theme } from "./constants/ThemeConfiguration";
import { store, persistor } from "./store";
import RootNavigator from "./navigators/RootNavigator";


export default (App) => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Lato-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <RootNavigator />
            </NavigationContainer>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "auth",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger))
);

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

Comment: Can you paste your rootReducer file ?

Comment: Added. Also got it fixed myself.

Comment: Can you please paste in "./reducers/rootReducer" (the file rootReducer.js above references). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it fixed. Its not there in any documentation or article. The problem is with the **persistConfig**. **Key** which is **root** here. It should be the name of the reducer which we want to persist. In my case it was **auth**.

Updated **persistConfig** will be as follows:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "auth",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what key to put if I want to persist an entire "combinedReducer"?

Comment: I haven't tried but i guess set a key for this combinedReducer and use that in persistConfig.

Comment: What do you mean "set a key for this combinedReducer"?

Comment: As i said i haven't tried, but just like i am using a key: "auth", you should have a key for the combined reducer